# How can I render a token within a token via rules mail action?

Tags: rules, tokens

I want to send a node via rules. I can send it using the [node:body] token. However, I want to be able to use tokens in the actual node body as well. (Note: These are not global tokens)

Think of it like a newsletter and in the body field I am using

Dear [field_ef_first_name], ...

I can get the token to render if I put it directly in the rules action mail message body, but if it is in the node body field itself, it doesn't render.

The name field is coming form a views rule loop.

Rule exported:

```
{ "rules_send_newsletter_when_published" : {
"LABEL" : "Send newsletter when published",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
"ON" : { "node_insert--blog" : { "bundle" : "blog" } },
"DO" : [
  { "VIEW LOOP" : {
      "VIEW" : "entityforms",
      "DISPLAY" : "views_rules_1",
      "ROW VARIABLES" : {
        "field_ef_email" : { "email" : "Email" },
        "field_ef_first_name" : { "first_name" : "First Name" }
      },
      "DO" : [
        { "mail" : {
            "to" : "[email:value]",
            "subject" : "[node:title]",
            "message" : "[node:body]",
            "language" : [ "" ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT]

While the other answers are workable, this is the simplest and closest to your current implementation using Views Rules.

First of all, be sure to **enable the module [PHP Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/php)**

Also: the body of your blog needs to use the following custom token format: `!first_name!`. This string gets replaced inside your rule with the value of the Entityform `field_ef_first_name` field.

Here's the exported version of the Rule, modified from your original. **SCROLL DOWN** for an explanation.

```
{ "rules_send_newsletter_when_published" : {
    "LABEL" : "Send newsletter when published",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "php", "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_insert--blog" : { "bundle" : "blog" } },
    "DO" : [
      { "VIEW LOOP" : {
          "VIEW" : "entityforms",
          "DISPLAY" : "views_rules_1",
          "ROW VARIABLES" : {
            "field_ef_first_name" : { "first_name" : "First name" },
            "field_ef_email" : { "email" : "Email" }
          },
          "DO" : [
            { "variable_add" : {
                "USING" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "value" : "\u003C?php\r\n$text = str_replace(\u0027!first_name!\u0027, $first_name, $node-\u003Ebody[LANGUAGE_NONE][0][\u0027value\u0027]);\r\necho $text;\r\n?\u003E"
                },
                "PROVIDE" : { "variable_added" : { "processed_body" : "Processed body" } }
              }
            },
            { "mail" : {
                "to" : "[email:value]",
                "subject" : "Subject",
                "message" : "[processed-body:value]",
                "language" : [ "" ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here's an explanation:

This implementation of your Rule uses the action "Add a Variable" before sending the email. I named this variable "processed_body." I use **PHP Evaluation** to set the value of this variable:

```
<?php
$text = str_replace('!first_name!', $first_name, $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']);
echo $text;
?>
```

Basically, this snippet replaces the "token" `!first_name!` with the value of the Views Rule loop-provided variable $first_name. Then, I use the variable `processed_body` to send in the email body.

NOTICE that you will need to manually process any other custom tokens that you would like to add to your Blog body. For example, if you want the body to contain the last name of the recipient (e.g. `!last_name!`), you'll need to manually add a `str_replace` function that replaces `!last_name!` with the correct value.

[EDIT 2]

Here's the code with an added `!last_name!` "token" replacement. I assume your entityform field is `field_ef_last_name` and it has been added to the Rules View as such.

```
{ "rules_send_newsletter_when_published" : {
    "LABEL" : "Send newsletter when published",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "php", "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_insert--blog" : { "bundle" : "blog" } },
    "DO" : [
      { "VIEW LOOP" : {
          "VIEW" : "entityforms",
          "DISPLAY" : "views_rules_1",
          "ROW VARIABLES" : {
            "field_ef_first_name" : { "first_name" : "First name" },
            "field_ef_email" : { "email" : "Email" },
            "field_ef_last_name" : { "last_name" : "Last name" }
          },
          "DO" : [
            { "variable_add" : {
                "USING" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "value" : "\u003C?php\r\n$text = str_replace(\u0027!last_name!\u0027, $last_name, $node-\u003Ebody[LANGUAGE_NONE][0][\u0027value\u0027]);\r\n$text =  str_replace(\u0027!first_name!\u0027, $first_name, $text);\r\necho $text;\r\n?\u003E"
                },
                "PROVIDE" : { "variable_added" : { "processed_body" : "Processed body" } }
              }
            },
            { "mail" : {
                "to" : "[email:value]",
                "subject" : "[node:title]",
                "message" : "[processed-body:value]",
                "language" : [ "" ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The PHP code in the added Rules Variable value is

```
<?php
$text = str_replace('!last_name!', $last_name, $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']);
$text =  str_replace('!first_name!', $first_name, $text);
echo $text;
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess my example is a little too basic. I tried to keep it simple but I guess if I need to stuff some php is there to get what I want, I need to be more specific. I am using a rules views loop to loop over results of entity form submissions. In the rues view, I am setting the variable field_ef_first_name and using the core "send mail".

Comment: I have also come across this issue for Mime mail, however I am using html mail due to other dependencies in the project. https://www.drupal.org/node/2791341

Comment: Could you export your Rule and paste in your OP above? That's probably the best way to understand what you have so far...

Comment: Will do. Added above in question.

Comment: @Nigel Waters, I'll my best to answer in the next couple days. Things have gotten busy...

Comment: @nigel_waters: please see my edited answer. I believe this solves your issue.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much. Bounty assigned. Any chance you can modify the example to include the last name token, just so I can see what the php code would look like if I need to add multiple tokens?

Comment: @Nigel Waters: see edited answer with the added !last_name! token replacement. Thanks

Comment: Perfect. You rock!

Comment: Sorry, I had to poke at this one again, but I am getting the following error after adding last name. Notice: Array to string conversion in eval() (line 2 of /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/rules/modules/php.eval.inc(125) : eval()'d code).

Comment: I believe this has to do with the View. Go to the View being used by the loop, click on "edit field info" and BE SURE to click "Use rendered result" for all fields.

Comment: Yup. That was it. Thank you so very much for your help on this. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Using tokens within the body of a node, combined with using `[node:body]` in a Rules Action, will only result in the token being included as is (without rendering). However, based on what you're trying to do, you may want to have a look at an entirely different approach to achieve your goal ...

Enable the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer), and have a look at [Active Users Email](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/forena/tree/repos/reports/drupaladmin/sample_active_users_letter.frx) (using FRX syntax), which is one of the samples included in the module (which can be used to eMail a ***template message body*** to all registered users).

These are the parts in this FRX file that are relevant to the question here:

- The datablock `drupal/active_users`, which is (just) an SQL statement that looks like so:

  `--ACCESS=access administration pages`

  `SELECT uid, name, mail, login, status`

  `FROM {users}`

  `WHERE status=1 order by name`
- The `frx:foreach="*"`, which will cause an iteration for each row included in the results of the data block, for everything inside that `div` (related to the datablock).
- The `div` with `class="email-body"`, which starts with `Dear {name}`, and which includes a ***replacement token*** indicated with `{name}`.
- The line with `<frx:doc type="email" />`, to enable document format "Send eMail".

After you enabled the module, and visit the relative path at `/reports/drupaladmin.sample_active_users_letter`, this is what will happen:

1. Run the SQL query (as contained in the datablock).
2. Iterate over each of the results returned by the datablock (SQL statement).
3. For each iteration resolve all the tokens (i.e. as within that `Dear {name}`).
4. Display how the eMail will actually look like (for each iteration).
5. Add link (upper right) titled "eMail". If you actually click that "eMail" link, a confirmation screen will be shown with these details:

   - number of eMails that will be eMailed (= number of rows in the datablock).
   - radio button to either send an eMail, or actually send all eMails.

With the above in mind, this is what you'd need to get it to work for your case:

- Clone the delivered sample, and tune it as detailed below.
- Adapt the datablock to retrieve the desired data (columns), similar to what your view is doing. Or create a new one that fits your needs and use that one instead. Make sure to include the data related to your `field_ef_email` and `field_ef_first_name`.
- Adapt the *From*, *To* and *Subject* to fit your needs.
- Use whatever tokens you need, anywhere in the *Body* of your eMail. E.g. to replace that `Dear {name}`. If you need more, or other, data, just add an appropriate name to your datablock (as an extra column). As a sample, here is part of an FRX file I created to transform webform submissions into some kind of followup-eMail to each of those who submitted the form:

  `<p>Hello,</p>`

  `<p>thank you for using our form (with node id = {node}) to submit your feedback (with submission id = {submission}). You're now confirmed via the eMail Id you entered (= {fieldvalue}) to receive eMails from us.</p>`

  `<p>We'll get back to you shortly for an additional followup eMail.</p>`

Answer (score 1):

The following creates a mail message based on a profile & commerce product, custom entity, commerce credit.

Trying to pull all these things in together without coding up your own rule or rule handler is a bit much too expect. The comment regarding random complexity and disparate objects means you don't have a sane alternative. This answer goes a long way out of the domain of rules.

There is mimemail in this setup to detect and send html mail.

I did start off with a handler, but the custom rule makes things explicit.

### Rule

```
function yhivepasses_rules_action_info() {
  $items = array();

  $items['yhivepasses_email_passes'] = array(
    'label' => t('Send pass email'),
    'group' => t('YogaHive Passes'),
    'parameter' => array(
    'commerce_order' => array(
      'type' => 'commerce_order',
      'label' => t('Order'),
      'description' => t('The order containing the credits bought.'),
    ),
  ),
  'callbacks' => array(
    'execute' => 'yhivepasses_rules_action_send_pass_on_checkout',
  ),
);

return $items;
}
```

### Callback function

I have just

```
function yhivepasses_rules_action_update_on_checkout($order) {
  $yogaHivePasses = new YogaHivePasses();
  $yogaHivePasses->checkoutRule($order);
}
```

### Data building classes

The callback function calls a set of classes that bring the data together from the rule and secondary sources.

I shove this all into a data object.

### Call drupal mail

```
protected function sendToStudio(YogaHivePassDao $passDao) {
 $message_studio_contact = [];
 $message_studio_contact['module'] = YogaHivePasses::MODULE_NAME;

 $this->studioContactEmail($message_studio_contact, $passDao);
 $langStudio = $this->mailSetLanguage($message_studio_contact, $passDao->getStudioUser());
 $result = drupal_mail(YogaHivePasses::MODULE_NAME, YogaHivePasses::EMAIL_KEY, $passDao->getStudioUser()->mail, $langStudio, $message_studio_contact);
}
```

This calls a method that builds the html mail body from a template.

### Mail template processing

This relies on hook_theme which defines the templates.

```
public function studioContactEmail(&$message, YogaHivePassDao $passDao) {

// Needs User object. Not bothering with printing out actual order details.
$content_templated = theme('yhivepasses_studiocontact_purchase_studio_email', array(
  'passDao' => $passDao,
 ));

 $content_templated .= theme('yhivepasses_email_footer', array());
 $message['body'][] = $content_templated;
 $message['subject'] = 'Studio pass purchased on YogaHive';
 $current_credit = current($credit);
 $message['subject'] .= ' ' . $current_credit->credit_type;

 $headers = array(
  'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
  'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed',
  'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => '8Bit',
  'X-Mailer' => 'Drupal'
 );
 foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
  $message['headers'][$key] = $value;
 }
}
```

### Hook mail

Hook mail is needed to add the body, subject and headers in the correct places.

```
function yhivepasses_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
 switch ($key) {
  case YogaHivePasses::EMAIL_KEY :
  $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
  $message['body'] = $params['body'];

  // May not be any parameters. Parameters are mainly used to send attachments. 
  if (array_key_exists('params', $params)) {
    $message['params'] = $params['params'];
  }

  foreach ($params['headers'] as $key => $value) {
    $message['headers'][$key] = $value;
  }
  break;
default:
  return;
```

}
 }